# Subtraction between two series on pine script

Tags: pine-script

I have a indicator that I need to plot the difference between 2 series:

Close Price ans FastSMA.

When i try to plot the difference the result is a plot that is not ok.

my code:

```
//@version=3
study(title="Simple moving averages example", overlay=true)

// Calculate moving averages
fastMA = sma(close, 7)
slowMA = sma(close, 33)

// Plot values


plot(series=fastMA, color=lime, linewidth=2)
plot(series=close, color=fuchsia, linewidth=2)
plot(series=dif, color=fuchsia, linewidth=2)

// Colour background when moving averages cross
bgcolor(color=cross(fastMA, slowMA) ? teal : na)
```

this is the result when plot withou the dif plot:

[image]

and this one is when i plot the diff:

[image]

Comment: What is "not ok"? `102.35 - 102.41 != -0.06`?

Answer (score 0):

if you have negative and positive numbers you can specify the style of plot to be histogram, like macd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).